# How build Typescript with imported packages properly for IE11 using Bable 7 and Webpack 4?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

Recently, we released a new version of an react app, but caused the IE11
complain the `let` keyword.

When I looked into, I found it was because we upgraded `query-string` package from `5.1.0` to `6.4.0`, and the new code used the `let` keyword like [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string/blob/a429c8e48d899fa302440ccb702e6c7ff8fd4621/index.js#L66). And it looks like our build process didn't compile the imported packages from `es6` to `es5`.

We are using `typescript` with `babel 7` and `webpack 4`, it all good for our own code and most packages except `query-string`.

The following are our configs, please suggest the best way to solve it.

**webpeck.config:**

```
  {
    test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: { transpileOnly: true }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["webworker", "esnext", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
  const presets = [
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          // React parses on ie 9, so we should too
          ie: 9
        },
        forceAllTransforms: true,
        // Disable polyfill transforms
        useBuiltIns: false,
        // Do not transform modules to CJS
        modules: false
      }
    ]
  ]
```

**sample source file**

```
  import queryStringLib from 'query-string'
  queryStringLib.stringify(...)
```

By the way, I have tried to remove `exlcude node_modules` in both `webpack.config` and `tsconfig.json`, doesn't work. I also tried to change `tsconfig.json` to target `es5`, doesn't work either.

**Update #1**
I just tried, It will work, if I remove `exclude node_modules` in both `webpack.config` and `tsconfig.json`, and change `tsconfig.json` to target `es5`. However it will make the computer a lot busier than before. Not a perfect solution.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 2):

To me, it worked if I changed webpack.config to:

```
{
    test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)query-string)/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: { transpileOnly: true }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In other words, exclude all other node_modules except `query-string` and add `@babel/preset-env` as a preset option to `babel-loader` (`babel-loader` did not work correctly without).

No changes to `tsconfig.json`.